# Rectangular Box Packing Algorithm: Fitting Rectangles

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, geometry

I'm working on a problem that involves performing two types of operations on rectangles. The operations are represented as an array, where each operation can be of one of the following two types:

[0, a, b] - This operation creates and saves a rectangle with dimensions a × b.

[1, a, b] - This operation checks whether all the previously saved rectangles can fit within a box of dimensions a × b. It's important to note that rectangles can be rotated by 90 degrees, meaning a rectangle with dimensions b × a is considered equivalent to one with dimensions a × b.

My code aims to determine if each of the "1" type operations can be satisfied, and it seems to work well for most test cases. However, there's one test case where it fails, and I'm struggling to identify the mistake. Can you help me find the error?

Here's my current solution:

```py
def solution(operations):
    res = []
    maxWidth = maxHeight = 0
    
    for t, a, b in operations:
        if t == 0:
            maxWidth = max(maxWidth, a)
            maxHeight = max(maxHeight, b)
            
        else:
            fits = (maxWidth <= a and maxHeight <= b or maxHeight <= a and maxWidth <= b)
            res.append(fits)

    return res
```

Comment: "there's one test case where it fails": which is...?

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't have it, unfortunately, I am running generated tests that are too big to have a look at it.

Comment: Your "1" type operations can only be satisfied with the rectangles processed so far by the for loop, is that the intent?

Comment: @Aldert Yes it is, "This operation checks whether all the previously saved rectangles"